# What do the schemes login, login_post, admin, and relative mean?

Tags: functions, site-url

[site_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) and [get_site_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url) accept a parameter named `$scheme`. `$scheme` can be set to `http`, `https`, `login`, `login_post`, `admin` or `relative`.

`http` and `https` are obvious.

What do `login`, `login_post`, `admin` and `relative` do? What scheme does each of these provide and when/why?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Codex](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3038)

```
if ( ! $scheme ) {
        $scheme = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
} elseif ( $scheme === 'admin' || $scheme === 'login' || $scheme === 'login_post' || $scheme === 'rpc' ) {
        $scheme = is_ssl() || force_ssl_admin() ? 'https' : 'http';
} elseif ( $scheme !== 'http' && $scheme !== 'https' && $scheme !== 'relative' ) {
        $scheme = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
}
```